# The image changes with any action with the video card drivers

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card

A long time ago I encountered a rather strange problem when updating the drivers for the **AMD Radeon RX470** video card. The bottom line is this: with any action with the drivers (update, rollback), the image on the monitor improves, it’s not entirely clear what exactly is changing, but as I understand it, the rendering resolution changes, i.e. the image becomes clearer. When the PC is restarted, everything falls back to how it was, the image becomes fuzzy, as if I were wearing glasses with lenses not under my eyes. Versions are installed correctly and this happens with any version of the driver; when restarting, the version is not reset. Please help me solve this problem, thanks in advance!

Comment: Check ClearType settings in Windows. Could be they're changed during the update process and revert afterwards.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, that is, see if they change when updating the driver? Are you sure that these settings will affect the whole picture, because they only apply to text. It's just that this function has only one flag on / off.

Comment: No, use the ClearType Text Tuner: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-make-text-easier-read-using-cleartype-windows-10

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, yes, I tried everything I could, but nothing changed.